# Pasar datos entre clases [python]

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Estoy intentando realizar para aprender un proyecto de un inventario con mongoDB.
Actualmente he tengo 2 clases,

clase MongoDB

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class MongoDB:
    def __init__(self, dbname):
        # establish a connection we’ll use the MongoClient object.
        self._conn = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
        self._db = self._conn[dbname]


    def createCollection(self, name=""):
        return self._db[name]

    def insertOneProduct(self, product):
        collection = self._db.productos

        insert = collection.insertOne(self)

        return self
```

La clase inventario:
En esta clase estaran las operaciones CRUD:

- añadir producto
- modificar producto
- buscar producto
- eliminar producto

```
from  config.database import MongoDB

class Inventario(object):
    """docstring for Inventario."""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Inventario, self).__init__()

    def add_product(self, nombre, precio, cantidad):

        new_product = {
            "nombre": nombre,
            "precio": precio,
            "cantidad": cantidad
        }

        insert = MongoDB.insertOneProduct(new_product)

        return new_product
```

Actualmente estoy intentando introducir datos en mi fichero app.py

```
from config.database import MongoDB
from classes.inventario import Inventario

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # you want to initialize the class
    database   = MongoDB("terranova")
    collection = database.createCollection("productos")
    myinventario = Inventario()

    articulo1 = myinventario.add_product('cocacola', 10, 1)
```

Pero al ejecutar esto me da el siguiente error.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
    articulo1 = myinventario.add_product('cocacola', 10, 1)
  File "/home/user/proyectos/GestionTienda/module/classes/inventario.py", line 17, in add_product
    insert = MongoDB.insertOneProduct(new_product)
TypeError: insertOneProduct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product'
```

Alguno me ayuda a saber qué es lo que no estoy entendiendo al hacer estos pasos de datos entre clases? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que está usando el class de MongoDB en vez del database objeto que creó en esta linea: `database = MongoDB("terranova")`. Por eso, esta arrojando el error `TypeError: insertOneProduct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product'`.

Esto sí lo puede hacer pero tiene que remover el `self` en la función de `insertOneProduct` para que sea un método de class o static. Pero no lo recomiendo.

En vez, recomiendo que separa los funciones de sus colecciones y pasar las colecciones a varios métodos.